# Compare two dataframes and handle comparison with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Imagine, you have two dataframes.
Both have a column "name" with exact the same values (here: A,B,C,D).
Now, the "values" shall be checked between the corresponding names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

df_base = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'value': ['x', 'y',np.nan,'x',np.nan],
    'date': ['01-01-1980','01-01-1980',np.nan,'01-01-1980',np.nan]})


df_upd = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A','B','C','D'],
    'value': ['x', np.nan,'x','y']})
```

In case of the values differ, df_base['date'] shall be updated as shown in the table. x = x is identical and shall remain on the old value. np.nan = np.nan has also np.nan in the date and shall remain untouched. All other cases shall be handled as difference and updated with the current date.

```
| name | value (df_base) | value (df_upd) |date (old)| date(new)     |
|------|-----------------|----------------|----------|---------------|
|   A  |        x        |         x      |01-01-1980| 01-01-1980    |
|   B  |        y        |       np.nan   |01-01-1980|dt.date.today()|
|   C  |      np.nan     |         x      |  np.nan  |dt.date.today()|
|   D  |        x        |         y      |01-01-1980|dt.date.today()|
|   E  |      np.nan     |       np.nan   |  np.nan  |    np.nan     |
```

In the end, I want this:

```
df_base = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'value': ['x', 'y',np.nan,'x',np.nan],
    'date': ['01-01-1980','*today*','*today*','*today*',np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dfs then update the `date` with today's if the values differ and both non `NaN` :

```
cmp = df_base.merge(df_upd, on="name", how="left", suffixes=(None, "_upd"))

# are both values NaN ?
m1 = cmp[["value", "value_upd"]].isna().all(axis=1)

# has the value been updated ?
m2 = cmp["value"].eq(cmp.pop("value_upd"))

cmp["date"] = cmp["date"].where(m1|m2, # or maybe you want %-d-%m-%Y ?
                  pd.Timestamp("today").strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
```

Output :

```
print(cmp)

  name value        date
0    A     x  01-01-1980
1    B     y  10-28-2023
2    C   NaN  10-28-2023
3    D     x  10-28-2023
4    E   NaN         NaN
```

Comment: ok, solution is appropriate.
Do you have an additional idea how to do this without a merge?